# No suma sino que concatena los datos

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

En la siguiente parte que coloco aquí me lee los valores pero no los suma sino que los concatena y no entiendo cuál es el problema.

```
var monto1 = hoja1.getRange(row,13).getValue();  
var monto2 = hoja1.getRange(row,15).getValue();
var monto3 = hoja1.getRange(row,19).getValue();
var monto4 = hoja1.getRange(row,21).getValue();

var montototal = monto1 + monto2 + monto3 + monto4 ;
    hoja1.getRange(row,5).setValue(montototal);
```

Comment: Tienes que convertirlos a entero, sea en la declaración, sea en la suma. En la declaración, tienes que haces con cada variable algo como esto: `var monto1 = parseInt( hoja1.getRange(row,13).getValue() );`   Entonces podrás sumar libremente. O bien en la suma: `var montototal = parseInt( monto1 ) + parseInt( monto2 ) + parseInt( monto3 ) +parseInt(  monto4 ) ;` creo que sería bueno establecer controles que no permitan en esas celdas valores no numéricos, pero ese es ya otro tema.

Comment: en efecto como te dicen es porque lo esta tomando como string y lo concatena para que sumes debes tomar su valor sea int, float, etc..

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que tener en cuenta el debil tipado de Javascript, a una variable de tipo Number le puedes asignar un String y viceversa y no lanzará errores. En el ejemplo que indicas si alguno de los sumandos es un string, lo que va a suceder es se va a concatenar todo el resultado. Iniciando de izquierda a derecha. Por ejemplo:

```
var a = "hola";
var b = 10;
var c = 5;

console.log( a + b + c);
//hola105

console.log( b + a + c);
//10hola5

console.log( b + c + a);
//15hola
```

En el primer ejemplo como el primer elemento es un string el signo "+" concatenará "a" y "b", y luego lo mismo con "c". 
En el segundo ejemplo pasará lo mismo solo que en diferente orden.
En el tercer ejemplo la cosa cambia, debido a que "b" y "c" son de tipo Number, primero se hace una suma entre ellos y luego se concatena con "c".

Comment: Bienvenido Carlos. A tu respuesta le falta incluir una sugerencia sobre cómo resolver el problema.

Answer (score 2):

***JavaScript* usa el signo + tanto para una suma como para concatenar strings**, así
cuando uno de los operadores de una suma es un string numérico, se concatena.

```
var a = 10;
var b = '5';

console.log(a + b); // 105
console.log(b + a); // 510
```

Si sabes, o sospechas, que uno de los números involucrados en la operación es un string, debes realizar la conversión a número antes de la suma:

```
var a = 10;
var b = '5';

a = parseInt(a);
b = parseInt(b);

console.log(a + b); // 15
console.log(b + a); // 15
```

Para la conversión de un string numérico a un número entero se ha usado la función [parseInt()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) de JavaScript.

Comment: Orci, hice lo siguiente:   var monto1 = hoja1.getRange(row,13).getValue();
      var m1 = parseInt(monto1);
    var monto2 = hoja1.getRange(row,15).getValue();
      var m2 = parseInt(monto2);
    var monto3 = hoja1.getRange(row,19).getValue();
      var m3 = parseInt(monto3);
    var monto4 = hoja1.getRange(row,21).getValue();
      var m4 = parseInt(monto4);
  
    var montototal = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4; 
     hoja1.getRange(row,5).setValue(montototal);    Pero me da como resultado esto:  #¡NÚM!   No entiendo qué ocurre

Comment: @Doug Oliva alguno de los variables simplemente no tienen un número. Deberás comprobar esto y descartarlas o igualarlas a 0 antes de sumarlas.

Comment: `parseInt` convierte la cadena a entero, pero no sabemos si los datos de la hoja de cálculo se puede convertir ni si son enteros.

Comment: NO SE QUÉ OCURRE, LOS DATOS VIENEN DE UN FORMULARIO QUE LLENA ALGUIEN Y CUANDO HAGO LA SUMA DE LAS CUOTAS LAS CONCATENA PERO SON NÚMEROS CONCATENADOS NO SUMADOS Y LA VERDAD NO ENTIENDO QUÉ OCURRE.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

Alguno de los valores que se han tomado no es número. Por ejemplo, las funciones de Hoja de Cálculo de Google interpretan como `0` las celdas vacías, pero Google Apps Script las interpreta como cadena vacía `""`.

Usa [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) e [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/isNaN) para descartar los valores que no sean número y [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) para realizar la suma. Los tres métodos son de JavaScript.

NOTA: Si el valor del lado de la hoja de cálculo es tipo texto pero incluye una coma como separador de decimales, antes de hacer la conversión de cadena a número deberá reemplazarse la coma como por punto debido a la sintaxis de JavaScript.

### Ejemplo

El siguiente ejemplo tiene fines ilustrativos, no contempla todos los posibles casos, como el de usar coma como separador de decimales en un valor tipo texto.

```
var monto1 = hoja1.getRange(row,13).getValue();  
var monto2 = hoja1.getRange(row,15).getValue();
var monto3 = hoja1.getRange(row,19).getValue();
var monto4 = hoja1.getRange(row,21).getValue();

var values = [monto1, monto2, monto3, monto4];
var soloNumeros = values.filter(function(a) {
return !isNaN(a);
});
var montototal = soloNumeros.reduce(function(a, b) {
return parseFloat(b) + a;
});
    hoja1.getRange(row,5).setValue(montototal);
```

### Comprobación

```js
var monto1 = "a";
var monto2 = 1;
var monto3 = 1;
var monto4 = "1";

var values = [monto1, monto2, monto3, monto4];
var soloNumeros = values.filter(function(a) {
return !isNaN(a);
});
var montototal = soloNumeros.reduce(function(a, b) {
return parseFloat(b) + a;
});
console.log(montototal)
```

## Explicación

En Google Apps Script, el método getValue de Class Range del Servicio de Hoja de Cálculo (SpreadsheetApp) devuelve

- una cadena vacía (`""`) como valor de las celdas vacías
- un número como valor de las celdas que tienen números
- un objeto fecha como valor de celdas que tienen números con formato de fecha, hora, duración, fecha-hora (internamente la hoja de cálculo de Google maneja estos datos como números seriales)
- una cadena para celdas que tienen valores tipo texto y mensajes de error (!#N/A, !#REF, etc.)
- un booleano para celdas que tienen valores booleanos (`VERDADERO`, `FALSO`)

Por otro lado JavaScript usa símbolo el `+` tanto como `operador suma` como `operador concatenar`. Si el primer operando es número, trata de convertir el segundo operando a número, si no puede, concatena. Si el primero operando es una cadena, lo concatena con el segundo operando.

Algunos usan métodos de JavaScript como [parseInt(*string*,*base*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) para convertir cadenas que incluyen números a número entero, por ejemplo, convertir `"10"` a `10`, así como métodos similares según corresponda al tipo de número deseado como resultado. Otros usan la validación de datos de la hoja de cálculo de Google pero esta no impide dejar una celda en blanco por lo que además podrías usar el método [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank) de Google Apps Script o bien [isNaN(*valor*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/isNaN) de JavaScript para determinar si el valor evaluado es un número.

Referencias

- [Expresiones y Operadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)